# Resizable textarea in a hidden div shrinks to unusable size with jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui

If a textarea is contained in a hidden div that will be shown later (i.e. a tab panel) and it is made to be resizable with jQuery UI resizable plubin, why does it shrink to near invisibility?

```
<div>
    <input type="button" onclick="$('#form_container').toggle();" value="show" />
</div>
<div>
    <form>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="form_container" style="display:none">
    <form>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </form>
</div>

$(function () {
    $("textarea").resizable();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cxrH3/3/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/cxrH3/4/

```
$(function () {
    $("textarea").resizable({minWidth: '150px'});
});
```

EDIT :

This also seems to work if you leave out the curly brackets.

```
$(function () {
    $("textarea").resizable(minWidth: 150);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cxrH3/5/

I'm not sure the reasoning behind it, but it seems like it just doesn't render the `({minWidth: 150})` correctly, or at all.. So just use one of the methods above.